# How can I add setcookie into ejabberdctl to run the ejabberd service or connect two node on different machine without setcookie in startup?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am new the Erlang. Currently, we are using ejabberd for our xmpp service.
Recently, dues to some capability issue, I have written a distributed erlange program. I need to run rpc:call between two machines. I can do the rpc:call successfully on erl simulator. But our current system was using ejabberdctl to start the ejabberd service. I have check and try to modify the ejabberdctl file. But I can't add -setcookie successfully.

the code section in ejabberdctl is

```
ctlexec()
{ 
    CONN_NAME=$1; shift
    COMMAND=$@
    $EXEC_CMD "$ERL \
    $NAME ${CONN_NAME} \
    -noinput \
    -hidden \
    -pa $EJABBERD_EBIN_PATH \
    $KERNEL_OPTS \
    -s ejabberd_ctl -extra $ERLANG_NODE $COMMAND"
}
```

the problem caused by the last two line:

```
  $KERNEL_OPTS \
  -s ejabberd_ctl -extra $ERLANG_NODE $COMMAND"
```

I think this file is referenced some one's before, but I don't know where are there from.
Does anybody know how can I add -setcookie abc to this erl command?
If I can't change the ejabberdctl file or the worse case, I can't change the current system.
i.e. I don't have a chance to add setcookie to the ejabberd system.
How can I connect my new node to the existing ejabberd node(our current system).

The ejabberd suppose to start first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a solution right under your nose. How `ctlexec()` works? It runs `--hidden` node named `$NAME ${CONN_NAME}`, sets options `$KERNEL_OPTS`, inserts `$EJABBERD_EBIN_PATH` into search path and calls `ejabberd_ctl:start()` with some additional parameters in `$ERLANG_NODE $COMMAND`. So there must be `-setcookie Cookie` parameter in `$KERNEL_OPTS` or it uses default cookie in `$HOME/.erlang.cookie`. It is exactly what you need. Just replace `-s ejabberd_ctl` with your own module and use `$KERNEL_OPTS` and `$ERLANG_NODE` content which you already have. Search around in the script for clues what `$KERNEL_OPTS` and `$ERLANG_NODE` contains.

It is a usual way how scripts like `ejabberd_ctl` are made. It is pretty simple and elegant. You just run your own node set it `--hidden` so you don't disturb other nodes in a cluster if there is such. Don't forget set some random node name. Connect to the application node and then do your `rpc:call/4,5` and that's it. There is usually some modules like `ejabberd_ctl.erl` to make it more comfortable, process extra parameters and so on.

Comment: Thanks, finally, I use the shared .erlang.cookie between two machines to avoid the modification of the ejabberctl file. I also see this method on ejabberd's document in cluster section.